# Помощь в написании шаблонной функции C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

прошу опытных товарищей подсказать как лучше реализовать шаблонную функцию. 
Предположим у меня есть такая структура:

```
struct MediaData
    {
        static void Init();
        static boost::shared_ptr<MediaData> ConstructorWithTupleHandler(const boost::python::tuple& tuple);
        static boost::shared_ptr<MediaData> ConstructorWithStringHandler(const std::string& str);
        static std::string __str__(const MediaData& mediaData);
        static std::string __repr__(const MediaData& mediaData);

        static const size_t mediaDataLen = 1024;

        BYTE* data();

    private:
        std::array<BYTE, mediaDataLen> m_mediaData;
    };
```

Функция ConstructorWithTupleHandler имеет данную реализацию:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MediaData> MediaData::ConstructorWithTupleHandler(const boost::python::tuple& tuple)
{
    auto mediaData = new MediaData;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < min(boost::python::len(tuple), mediaDataLen); ++i)
    {
        mediaData->m_mediaData[i] = boost::python::extract<BYTE>(tuple[i]);
    }
    return boost::shared_ptr< MediaData >(mediaData);
}
```

Вопрос вот в чем: у меня имеется не одна структура подобной MediaData у которых различие в поле **static const size_t mediaDataLen** и в поле **std::array m_mediaData**. Расскажите пожалуйста, как можно для данной функции написать функцию - шаблон, чтобы избежать повторов в коде. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: шаблонная функция (по моему) тут неуместна  для довольно узкого круга  типов  .  Я бы написал базовый абстрактный класс для всех этих структур, и в функции уже работать с указателем на этот базовый класс.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Согласен, если бы проект был написан с нуля, то скорее всего так и стоило бы поступить, но в моем случае не совсем подходит такое решение

Answer (score 0):

Логичнее, на мой взгляд, это вынести в отдельный статический метод:

```
template<typename _DataStruct>
static boost::shared_ptr<_DataStruct> ConstructorWithTupleHandler(const boost::python::tuple& tuple)
{
    auto data = _DataStruct::ArrayType();   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < min(boost::python::len(tuple), _DataStruct::DataLen); ++i)
        data[i] = boost::python::extract<typename _DataStruct::ArrayType::value_type>(tuple[i]);

    return boost::make_shared<_DataStruct>(std::move(data));
}

struct MediaData
{
    static constexpr size_t DataLen = 1024;
    using ArrayType = std::array<BYTE, DataLen>;
    MediaData(ArrayType data) : m_mediaData(std::move(data)) {}

    /*...*/

private:
    ArrayType m_mediaData;
};
```